# GhostScript PDF to PostScript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have to convert pdf files (created with jasperreports) to postscript.

I'm using ghostscript (Version 9.19) to make the conversion.

The commmand i'm using is:

```
gswin64c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=file.ps file.pdf
```

The conversion is done without problem, but when i open the postscript file generated (using GSview 5.0), the top margin is crop by 2-3 cm, and some information to print is lost.

I have changed the device from `ps2write` to `eps2write`, used the property -`g<width>x<height>` with the page size in pixels, but the problem persist.

The file is to be printed in a preformated paper, so i can not use the postscript generated to print.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: you might add -sPAPERSIZE=legal or -sPAPERSIZE=a4 or experiment with this

Comment: I'm afraid neither will have any effect, since they are overridden by the media size from the PDF file (unless you specify -dFIXEDMEDIA as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to say with great certainty, but it sounds like the PDF mediaBox is larger than the media you have specified to GSView.

You can try using the -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS along with -dFIXEDMEDIA and -dPDFFitPage, that should allow you to set up a specific media size, override the size in the PDF file **and** scale the result to fit the specified size.

Perhaps you could post an example PDF file, without that its very hard to comment sensibly.